# jQuery show hidden content

Tags: jquery, html, css, hidden-field

I have an idea in my head, however I am stuck.
I'm looking to make page with a fixed Navigation Bar with the following links:
Portfolio
About
Contact

Now, rather than having the "About" section loading into a new page, I would like to have
a div box about 470x330px slide down from under the "Navigation Bar" itself, once I click on the "About" link.

Here is how I formatted my code for the Navigation:

```
<li><a href="#" class="menu-button menu-drop"><span class="menu-label">Portfolio</span></a>
<div class="menu-dropdown menu-dropdown2">
<ul class="menu-sub">
<li><a href="index1.php?page=peoples" class="menu-subbutton"><span class="menu-label">People</span>
<div class="menu-desc">portraits/full figure</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="menu-subbutton"><span class="menu-label">Products</span>
<div class="menu-desc">commercial base</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="menu-subbutton"><span class="menu-label">Landscapes</span>
<div class="menu-desc">various landscapes</div></a></li>
<li><a href="index1.php?page=personal" class="menu-subbutton"><span class="menu-label">Personal</span>
<div class="menu-desc">personal aspects</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="menu-subbutton"><span class="menu-label">Graphic Design</span>
<div class="menu-desc">various designs</div></a>
</li></ul></div></li> 
<li><a href="#" class="menu-button"><span class="menu-label">About</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="menu-button"><span class="menu-label">Contact</span></a></li>
```

Here is a really cool example, just click on the "About": http://www.nicolastarierphotography.com/

Comment: A few things to consider when building a website like this: Search Engines may have difficulty accurately indexing unique pages of your site. Also, linking directly to specific pages of your site from external sources becomes more difficult

Comment: hmm I never knew that, but is there a different method to achieve the look without the indexing issue?

Comment: There are plugins (or you could build one yourself) that use # (hash tags) in the URL to emulate site navigation / history - that would also let you link directly to the page with the div in question open. Check out the "seeing it work" section http://balupton.github.io/jquery-history/demo/ here for an example

Comment: Also, in reference to the SEO part of my comment above, I believe if you implemented a hash-tag navigation like this, using a sitemap that pointed to specific "pages" (with the hash tags in-tact) might help with SEO. But I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

### [A Pure CSS Solution?](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Q4E3h/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><input id='dropdown' type='checkbox' /><label for='dropdown'>Dropdown</label>
        <div>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    float:right;
    margin-right:50px;
}
li input[type=checkbox] ~ div{ 
    position:absolute;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
}
li label{
    margin-left:-20px;
    background:white;
}
li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div{
    max-height:200px;
}
```

Comment: goodness, that looks really neat actually.
I'm going to give it a try right now :)
thank you

Comment: how would I add this as a link in the navigation section?

Comment: I like, but how could I convert it into an actually href link to add into my existing navigation?
Example format:
<li><a href="#" class="menu-button"><span class="menu-label">About</span></a></li>

Comment: It relies on checkboxes and labels, but unless you are redirecting to an external page or an anchor...You dont need to use an anchor tag- just style the elements above